# How to construct a URL from a Twitter direct-message id?

Tags: twitter

For tweets, if you have the id of the account and the tweet you can construct a valid url like this:

https://twitter.com/{accountid}/status/{tweetid}

Is it possible to construct a similar url with a {directmessageid}? (Of course, the URL will be only reachable for the owner of the direct message.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no.

On mobile, you can see all the DMs you have shared with me (@edent) by visiting:

```
https://mobile.twitter.com/edent/messages
```

But there's no way to link to a specific message in that thread.

On the regular web version, to  link to a specific user try this url:

```
https://twitter.com/direct_messages/create/edent
```

I don't know why there are two different schemes for mobile and desktop - and I wish there were a simple way to link to an individual message.

Comment: twitter docs are so bad on this, please get it together twitter